# work around rails table naming conventions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to make friends rails with system with another database naming conventions. Is there possible to work around rails naming conventions? At least database table naming. It would be desirable to key name be just add '_id' suffix to table name. For example result join condition wanted like this `'parent'.'id'` = `'child'.'parent_id'`. If solution exists what is the invisible underwater rocks of solution?

Comment: devoters with no reason is unusable and harmfully

Comment: The downvote button has a tooltip "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". I suggest that you edit your question and fix at least your sentence structure. Look at this sentence:  "For example result join wanted like table 'parent'.'id' = 'child'.'parent_id'  "

Comment: Thanks. Some edit maked, possible it is better to read now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to work around rails naming conventions.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#overriding-the-naming-conventions

See also the many options you can specify for associations, like `class_name`, `foreign_key`, `primary_key`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

If you are a rails beginner, you should just use the rails conventions. All examples you find use them, and you just introduce an additional source of bugs.

For me overriding the naming conventions is only useful when you have an already existing databases.